# comparing two list of strings in C#

Tags: c#, list, linq, compare

There are Candidate and Job entities:

```
public class Candidate
{
    public int CandidateId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string SkillTags { get; set; }

    public List<string> skillTagsList
    {
        get
        {               
            return Array.ConvertAll(SkillTags.Split(','), p => p.Trim()).ToList();
        }
    }
}

public class Job
{
    public int JobId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Company { get; set; }
    public string Skills { get; set; }

    public List<string> skillsList
    {
        get
        {
            return Array.ConvertAll(Skills.Split(','), p => p.Trim()).ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

For each job, I want to get the candidates with most matching skills.
This LINQ query returns an error. is there a better LINQ query to get the results?

```
List<Candidate> candidates = repository.GetCandidates().Result;
List<Job> jobs = repository.GetJobs().Result;
List<Candidate> JobCandidates = null;
jobs.ForEach(j =>
{
    JobCandidates = candidates.Where(c => c.skillTagsList.Any(st => j.skillsList.Contains(st.ToLower())));
}
```

Comment: Use `Join` instead of `where` and `any` method.

Comment: @Sham how does that help in this context?

Comment: FYI your list properties can be made simpler just by doing: `public List<string> skillsList => Skills.Split(',').Select(s => s.Trim()).ToList();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each job project (`.Select`) a new object containing the job and the candidate with the top number of matching skills (`OrderDescendingBy` the number of intersections):

```
var result = jobs.Select(j => new {
    Job = j,
    Candidate = candidates.OrderByDescending(c => c.skillTagsList.Intersect(j.skillsList).Count())
                          .First()
});
```

Comment: Yes your solution solved my problem, thanks for that.